# autoencoders , show encoded data

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

i've created a convolutional autoencoder and i've been trying to show the encrypted data but it didn't work for me i need help with it if any one can help ....
this is the code i've been trying but it didn't work for me .

```
for i in range(10):
    # display original images
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 20, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(example_images[i].reshape(28,28))
    plt.gray()
  
# display reconstructed images
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 20, 20 +i+ 1)
    plt.imshow(reconst_images[i].reshape(28,28))
    plt.gray()
   

plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work for me" mean?  What error messages do you get?  what is `example_images`? Making a [mcve] would help.

Comment: I don't see issues in this code snippet, maybe you have problems in the dimensionality of the output images